# Trying to understand how CGI and AJAX work -- why isn't this demo working?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, cgi

So I'm trying to understand how all this works and I found a great little demo.

I have a CGI script called simple-ajax-example.cgi residing in the cgi-bin directory of my web server.

```
#!C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
use CGI;

$query = new CGI;

$secretword = $query->param('w');
$remotehost = $query->remote_host();

print $query->header;
print "<p>The secret word is <b>$secretword</b> and your IP is <b>$remotehost</b>.</p>";
```

I also have an .html file, called simpleAJAX.html (from my understanding, irrelevant what I name this file).  I wasn't sure where to place this, so I put it in the cgi-bin directory as well..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Ajax Example</title>
<script language="Javascript">
function xmlhttpPost(strURL) {
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {
            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText);
        }
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());
}

function getquerystring() {
    var form     = document.forms['f1'];
    var word = form.word.value;
    qstr = 'w=' + escape(word);  // NOTE: no '?' before querystring
    return qstr;
}

function updatepage(str){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="f1">
  <p>word: <input name="word" type="text">  
  <input value="Go" type="button" onclick='JavaScript:xmlhttpPost("/cgi-bin/simple-ajax-example.cgi")'></p>
  <div id="result"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I open up two tabs in my browser, navigate to both files.  All is well, until I go to update the field within simpleAJAX.html.  I type "Hello" and click Go, but the word is not updating in simple-ajax-example.cgi within my browser.  Any ideas?  The demo I am learning from is here: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php

Comment: All your perl script does is accept a url parameter and print it, then exit.    What is it that you expect to happen?

Comment: Is your script permissions set to executable and does your server have cgi/perl properly setup? This is also a really old way to do AJAX.

Comment: @gview, I expected it to behave as it did in the demo, which is in the link that I provided......

Comment: @tremor, yes, my permissions are set to executable.  I added this within my httpd.conf file, if I understand what you are asking.

Comment: could you elaborate more on why this is an old way?

Comment: Your description is far from clear.  You stated you opened up 2 tabs, one to the html page and one to the cgi script.  Then you state that the cgiscript doesn't update.  Huh?  Only the html page is supposed to update.  If your description is simply confused, and you are actually only looking at the html page, and it is not updating, then use the console in firebug to determine whether or not the cgi script is responding and if so, with what.

Comment: I misunderstood what was supposed to happen then. I realize part of the issue is when I click "Go" the message that's supposed to print does not appear at all.  I don't know what firebug is but I'll Google it.  thanks..

Comment: What's weird is when I navigate to the file path: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20%28x86%29/AM/HTTPServer/cgi-bin/simpleAJAX.html, it works.  But when I navigate to localhost/cgi-bin/simpleAJAX.html I receive an internal server error.

Upon debugging I'm getting: 
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
[Break On This Error]  

self.xmlHttpReq.send(getquerystring());

Answer (score 0):

Perl cgi is 100% ok
html ajax 100% ok

so debug it step by step

1, On clicking a button does the cgi script execute? YES/NO
   how-to check (put some line in the cgi to create a file for example)
   if NO check if "/cgi-bin/simple-ajax-example.cgi" is the correct path to your cgi
   and also the rights

> yes, my permissions are set to executable. I added this within my httpd.conf file

NO it's **chmod 755** simple-ajax-example.cgi
The command with which you set executable right to the file
It has nothing to do with httpd.conf which is actually one of the few config files of the server itself

if yes than go further in the code and check return value but I am sure that the answer is your cgi doesn't execute

Comment: my cgi script is supposed to print my IP address and the "secret word" that I type in the form, so no, it's not executing at all as nothing appears when I click Go.

I can't do chmod 755 as I am doing this on Windows, not Linux/Unix.  Sorry, I should have mentioned that.  I'm checking the permissions now.. thanks.

Comment: when I said I added it to httpd.conf, I was following the set up manual for Apache and it said to add the line  Options +ExecCGI under some directory permissions in ScriptAlias.  Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Permissions look good.. I set them to Full for system, admin and user on both files :/

Comment: Oh I see, it's windows., still not sure if cgi executes at all. it  minor thing both cgi and client side script are good. I still think cgi is not called, check if "/cgi-bin/simple-ajax-example.cgi" is the correct path bear in mind that path and the path you should use might be different.
 h ttp:/ / localhost/cgi-bin/simple-ajax-example.cgi instead you can check it by typing it as the url it should print out 'The secret word is <b></b> and your IP is <b></b>' Note that variables are empty since you didn't pass anything to you script this time just called it directly